# C++ no suitable constructor exists to convert from

Tags: c++, arrays, concatenation

We were provided with a template for a program and to finish it, here is our Main.cpp, at line `grocery[n++] = Grocery(thisName, no);` we think that its trying to concatenate the itemname(thisName) and the number (no) into an array, but we're getting an error, Not really sure how to input two different types of inputs (string + int) into one array to have an output that looks like this:

```
Grocery List
Number              Name
--------------------------------------
 Cheese - Cheddar   1002
 Fish - Cod         1011
 Spinach            2374
 Peppercorns        2953
 Cream              8543
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
#include "Main.h"
#include "Grocery.h"
void sort(Grocery* grocery, int n);
int main() {
    int no, n = 0;
    Grocery grocery[MAX_GROCERIES];
    cout << "Grocery List Processor\n";
    cout << "======================\n";
    do {
        cout << " Grocery number (0 to quit) ? ";
        cin >> no;
        if (cin.fail() || (cin.get() != '\n')) {
            cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
            cerr << "Bad character. Try again." << endl;
            cin.clear();
        }
        else if (no != 0) {
            cout << " Grocery name ? ";
            char thisName[MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1];
            cin.getline(thisName, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
            if (strlen(thisName) > 0)
                    grocery[n++] = Grocery(thisName, no);

        }
    } while (no != 0 && n < MAX_GROCERIES);
    cout << endl;
    sort(grocery, n);
    cout << " Grocery List\n\n";
    cout << " Name Number\n";
    cout << "------------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        grocery[i].display();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
// sort sorts the elements of Grocery[n] in ascending order
//
void sort(Grocery* grocery, int n) {
    int i, j;
    Grocery temp;
    for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (grocery[j].isGreaterThan(grocery[j + 1]))
            {
                temp = grocery[j];
                grocery[j] = grocery[j + 1];
                grocery[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

grocery.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Grocery.h"


using namespace std;

void Grocery::display() const{
        char* grocItem = nullptr;
        int prodID = '\0';

}
void Grocery::display(char *, int){
    grocItem = "";
    prodID = 15;

}
```

EDIT:--------------------------------

```
Grocery::Grocery(const char *name, const int ID, const int num){
    grocItem = *name;
    prodID = ID;
    numTimes = num;

}

Grocery& Grocery::operator=(const Grocery &rhs){

    grocerylist = new char[numTimes];
    for (int i = 0; i < numTimes; i++){
        grocerylist[i] = grocItem + prodID;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Here is our assignment operator and our standard overloaded constructor, but Visual studio gives us a weird error:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class Grocery & __thiscall Grocery::operator=(class Grocery const &)" (??4Grocery@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl sort(class Grocery *,int)" (?sort@@YAXPAVGrocery@@H@Z)


Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall Grocery::isGreaterThan(class Grocery const &)const " (?isGreaterThan@Grocery@@QBE_NABV1@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl sort(class Grocery *,int)" (?sort@@YAXPAVGrocery@@H@Z)  C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Workshop5\Workshop5\Main.obj  Workshop5
```

and a bunch of other weird ones..

Comment: It seems that `Grocery` is a class that has two members: `grocItem` which is a string, and `prodID` which is an integer. The line that you mentioned is constructing a `Grocery` item based on the given name and ID and puts it in an array of groceries (`grocery`). However, your implementation of `display` doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Like i said, it was a template provided and we are suppose to complete it, we are required to have a safe state display() and a overloaded display() and we were just using placeholders and we are going step by step through main.cpp to complete it, and got stuck on 'grocery[n++] = Grocery(thisName, no);' as we have no idea what its trying to do

Comment: I see. So you need to write a constructor for the `Grocery` class. In your case, you need to have a `Grocery(const char *name, const int ID)` constructor to make the line `grocery[n++] = Grocery(thisName, no);` work. You also need a copy assignment operator (and a copy constructor).

Comment: We do the copy assignment operator inside the grocery constructor we just made?

Comment: Grocery(thisName, no); Is a parameterized constructor. the Grocery class would be implementing this. Check for this in the class. If not u need to implement this. Also as @triple_r pointed out. Please check your display function. It should display the items in the array.

Comment: How would we combine a string and an int (*name and ID in this case) into an array?

Comment: copy assignment operator is different from a constructor. For that line of code to work, first `Grocery(name, no)` is going to construct an object using the constructor, then `grocery[n++] = ...` needs to copy the object that you just created into the array, so you need to have a copy assignment `Grocery &operator=(const Grocery &rhs)`.

Comment: so inside`'Grocery &operator=(const Grocery &rhs)` we copy `thisName` and `no` into different variables inwhich we then use the `void Grocery(const char *name, const int ID)` constructor to populate our array? These are all new terms for us so i apologize in advance.

Comment: Added an edit in the main post.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::string` or are you restricted to using c-strings?

Comment: Because you are using `char *` you cannot just copy `name` into `grocItem`, you need to allocate enough memory to `grocItem` then copy the content. Also, a constructor doesn't return anything, you need to remove the `void` from the beginning of your constructor definition. After you've done those changes, you are already passing both `grocItem` and `ID` to one array usiong the line `grocery[n++] = ...` in that you are creating a new object that has both of those in it, and then creating an array of those objects.

Comment: another edit in post above~

Comment: You have several people helping you.  Just an observation: Using char and UDT arrays,  not to mention your own hand-written version of bubble-sort, you are essentially writing C with some smattering of C++ thrown in.  Use `std::vector` and `std::string`, use `std::sort`.  Of course, it will look very different from the template you've been given -- and that would be a good thing.

Comment: Those errors are because in `grocery.h` where the class is defined, there are some member functions that are declared but you haven't defined them. One is the copy constructor (`Grocery &operator=(const Grocery &)`) and some other member functions. You need to define all the member functions in the `Grocery` class for your code to work.

Comment: As some others have mentioned (like @HappyGreenKidNaps and @AtlasC1) if you use `string`s instead of `char *` and `vector<Grocery>`s instead of `Grocery[]` it will make your life a lot easier, but I wasn't sure if that is allowed since you have been given a template to fill out.